# In jQuery does the advanced CSS3 selection style work in all browsers?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I'm watching a tutorial learning JQuery for the first time, and it seems you can select items using pretty much CSS, like:

```
$('ul li:nth-child(3)').addClass('biscuits');
```

Is that kind of selector going to work on all browsers, or just ones that support CSS 3 ?

Comment: It is going to work in all browsers - jQuery has its own implementation for this, it doesn't rely on the browser's selector support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work fine in all browsers **[JQuery actually supports.](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility)**

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question most accurately.

Answer (score 1):

It should work in all browsers - indeed, that is the main strength of jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it works on all browsers that jQuery supports. Which is more than plenty. The technique here doesn't rely on CSS but on JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It should work on all jQuery-supported browsers. It uses an internal selector engine to even out non-CSS3 browsers (cough, cough, IE). You shouldn't use a library though as it basically inhibits standards progress (and stems the flow of users away from IE).

Comment: Firefox 2.0 was bad, but think about chronologically. At the time, IE had IE6, which was a true abomination.

Comment: Re: “You shouldn't use a library though as it basically inhibits standards progress (and stems the flow of users away from IE).” Whilst I appreciate the point you’re making, that’s a pretty ridiculous position to take when faced with customer requirements.

Comment: It depends on your audience. A business might require IE support, but a personal blog about web development (where you'd most likely like to make a point) mightn't.